# Can I use "grinding" meaning "screeching"?

Tags: word-choice

Can I use "grinding" meaning "screeching"?

For example,

> Jack, you need to add some oil to your bike's hubs. The cogs are
>   grinding so loud, they are really annoying me!

or it sounds awkward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You example sentence is grammatically and semantically good.

However, IMO grinding and screeching are different noises.

Grinding is a mid-range frequency sound.

Screeching is a high frequency sound (at least to a human ear) and distinct from grinding.

Cogs grinding together could cause a screeching sound, but that would not be a grinding sound. The action is separate from the noise it produces. So, it would depend on what sound the cogs were emitting as they ground together as to which you used.

If it's more dawn chorus outside your window, then it's screeching.

If it closer to the noise of teeth grinding together then it's a grinding sound.

Comment: +1 : but what kind of songbirds do you have in your garden?

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest Graunching.

Wictionary defines it as:

Verb[edit]
graunch (third-person singular simple present graunches, present participle graunching, simple past and past participle graunched)
To grind or crunch (make sound of)